# Possibly having trouble on where to put my .dat file

Tags: c++

For my project I'm supposed to design a payroll class that has data members for an employee's hourly pay rate and number of hours worked.Write a program with an array of seven objects. The program should read the number of hours each employee worked and their hourly pay rate from a file and call class functions to store this information in the appropriate objects. It should then call a class function, once for each object, to return the employee's gross pay, so this information can be displayed.
I have a payroll.dat file that I was also supposed to use that I will show below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Payroll {
public:
    void setHours(double hours) {
        hoursWorked = hours;
    }
    void setRate(double rate) {
        hourlyRate = rate;
    }
    double getGrossPay() const {
        return hoursWorked * hourlyRate;
    }
private:
    double hoursWorked;
    double hourlyRate;
};

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile("payroll.dat");
    if (!inputFile) {
        cerr << "Error opening file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    Payroll employees[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        double hours, rate;
        inputFile >> hours >> rate;
        employees[i].setHours(hours);
        employees[i].setRate(rate);
    }
    inputFile.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        cout << "Employee " << i + 1 << " gross pay: $" << employees[i].getGrossPay() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

payroll.dat is below:

```
40.0   10.00
38.5    9.50
16.0    7.50
22.5    9.50
40.0    8.00
38.0    8.00
40.0    9.00
```

When I run the program I'm getting the message that says there's an error opening the file. I currently have the payroll file in my source files folder. Do I need to move it somewhere else? Thank you so much to anyone who can help!

Comment: the file should be where the executable is

Comment: I put the payroll.dat file in the source files where the c++ file is. Is there where it should be?

Comment: How are you running the code? Which directory are you running the executable in? That's where your file path is relative to

Comment: the source file and its location is irrelevant once you compiled the code. Actually I was wrong, its not the directory of the executable, but as Alan says, the directory from which you execute it